# MySQL query to output data with column headings from table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in SQL of getting the data shown in the left table to be output as in the picture on the right?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite, static list of tests, and no user taking a test more then once, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT UserID, 
       SUM(Result * (Unit = "Test 1")) AS "Test 1",
       SUM(Result * (Unit = "Test 2")) AS "Test 2",
       SUM(Result * (Unit = "Test 3")) AS "Test 3" 
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID;
```

This works by using SUM over a GROUP as a weighted sum of all entries with a weight of `1` for the line with the matching test and `0` for all other lines (the comparison evaluates to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE).

**Edit**

As @Nick pointed out in his comment, you can go a more readable and less implementation-dependent way using a CASE instead of the multiply-by-boolean style:

```
SELECT UserID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = "Test 1" THEN Result ELSE 0 END) AS "Test 1",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = "Test 2" THEN Result ELSE 0 END) AS "Test 2",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = "Test 3" THEN Result ELSE 0 END) AS "Test 3"
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'Test 1' THEN Result ELSE 0 END) AS \`Test 1\`` is more traditional and doesn't rely on a boolean being treated as 1 or 0.

Comment: I concurr, you are right, and it is probably better optimizable too. Didn't think that far :-)

Comment: This work only if you have static units "test1","test2",... if you add new test cases you must update the query. It's bettere to use pivot tables, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table